# Return boolean for element of tuple is in list of tuples

Tags: haskell, boolean

I am trying to return a `True/False` if a given `String` is part of a list of tuples.

I have some code that does it, but I am sure this is doable in a far better manner. Here's my code:

```
givenStringExists :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> Bool
givenStringExists u []  =   False
givenStringExists u (r:rs)
    |   u == fst(r)     =   True
    |   otherwise       =   givenStringExists u rs
```

Any suggestions for a means to improve it? At the moment I am having to call it from a filter passing in the list (hence the need for the `Bool`) and want to be able to do it without having to call on this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a concise way to do it

```
givenStringExists u theList = u `elem` map fst theList
```

Comment: Flawless. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write functions in parentheses, so you could write `fst r`.

Secondly, you can also do pattern matching in another pattern match, so like this:

```
...
givenStringExists u ((s,i):rs)
    |   u == s     =   True
...
```

Thirdly, you could also skip the guards. Via lazy evaluation and the use of `||` (or), this will only evaluate the list until one given string is found:

```
givenStringExists u ((s,i):rs) = u==s || givenStringExists u rs
```

Because of lazy eveluation, `||` will stop when the left hand side is `True`, because that is when the or will always be `True`, no matter what the other results are. In `&&`, the same things holds for finding one that is `False`: if the left hand side is `False`, the right hand side does not matter, because the overall expression will be `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another spin on [jamshidh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35923202/1477667) that combines the `map fst` with the `elem` by digging under the hood a tad.

```
import Data.Monoid (Any (..))
import Data.Foldable (Foldable (foldMap))

givenStringExists :: (Foldable f, Eq a)
                  => a -> f (a, b) -> Bool
givenStringExists a =
  getAny . foldMap (Any . (a ==) . fst)
```